# TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, random, tuples

I have x0 which is a float64 (64,64) array. Whenever I try this:

```
    delta = np.random.randn(x0.shape)
```

It gives the captioned error. This is so basic that I'm wrapping my heads around it. What am I missing out? Thanks

The complete traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-31-dcd2365ed519>", line 1, in <module>
    delta = np.random.randn(x0.shape)

  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1420, in mtrand.RandomState.randn

  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1550, in mtrand.RandomState.standard_normal

  File "mtrand.pyx", line 167, in mtrand.cont0_array

TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: what is `type(x0.shape)`?

Comment: @MoxieBall: It's a tuple but I'm wondering why.

Comment: Why are you wondering? Doesn't your code create this object? In any event, perhaps you can use the unpacking operator `*`:  `np.random.randn(*x0.shape)`

Comment: @JohnColeman: Shouldn't it return an array type?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`np.random.randn()` requires integer arguments, in the form `randn(64,64)`. You are giving `np.random.randn()` arguments in the form `randn((64,64))`, which it is not expecting. Instead, if you want to build a 64x64 random array, you will need to pass the number of rows and columns individually, not as a tuple.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like `np.random.randn()` expects an integer instead of a tuples:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html
try `np.random.randn(x0.shape[0], x0.shape[1])`

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem but it should be flexible enough to understand the difference, I guess?

Comment: or `np.random.randn(*x0.shape)`

Answer (score 2):

To debug this, I recommend including these line before you try to define delta:

```
print(x0)
print(type(x0))
```

`x0` is a tuple, but you're trying to use it in the `np.random.randn` function, which only accepts integers as arguments. If you want a multidimensional array of random numbers (for example, a 3x7x6 array), you can use `np.random.randn(3, 7, 6)`.